# Data Factory Salesforce to SQL Server different value for Byte[] field

Tags: sql-server, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I created a copy activity where the source dataset is a salesforce system using a query where I only get one(1) record for in testing and inserting it to the SQL Server table. But what happens is that the source body value is different from the sink body when the copy is completed. The source data type is a Byte[], for the sink I tried different data types such as NVARCHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, VARBINARY but the actual value is still different. The source is a BASE64 value but on the sink it seems different and I don't know where the conversion is happening.

First part value of the **Source** Body from Salesforce:

[image]

First part value of the **Sink** Body from SQL Server:

[image]

Comment: You could try to convert the string in SQL database table to base64 string, to check if they are same. Please try the VARCHAR(MAX) in SQL server.

Comment: Hi @Erldrine Mangawang, did you solve it now?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue, the outcome is still the same, as I've said in the Question details as well I have tried NVARCHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, and VARBINARY with MAX length and the outcome is the same.

Comment: I create a base64 value in blob and copy it to SQL table(schema varchar(max) ), it all works well. It's very strange···

Comment: Did you set the record as string when mapping to the SQL table?